# Stripe quantity based billing - Invoice is already paid

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I will try to give the most context to this issue as possible. In stripe, I have a prorated subscription setup that bills the user on a monthly basis, this subscription needs to be quantity-based as the user can have multiple instances of that plan at once. Each time the user creates a new 'entity' the quantity of the subscription is increased by one to match the amount of 'entities' that the user has.

A user can create a new 'entity' at any time, every time they add a new 'entity' a new invoice is generated and they are immediately charged. There is a billing cycle anchor set for the end of the month so they are only charged for the remaining amount of days for the current month.

The user can also chose to stop paying for an 'entity' at any time when this happens the quantity of the stripe subscription is decreased by one. They can continue using that 'entity' until the end of the month and then will not be charged when the next month arrives.

However this has the unintended behaviour as the quantity does not match the current amount of 'active' entities in the system.

To show this I will provide a diagram that shows the behavior that creates the "invoice is already paid" error message. I will also show code snippets to give greater understanding.

[image]

Is there any way around this or will I have to switch single subscriptions for each entity? Thanks

Also here is the error exact error message

```
[2020-05-04 10:39:21] local.INFO: (Status 400) (Request req_nKlw7rJHdFJujL) Invoice is already paid
```

And here are some code snippets

Increment quantity code

```
    public function incrementSubscription(CompanySubscription $subcription, Team $team) {
        try {
            $quantity = $item->quantity + 1;
            $stripe_sub = StripeBiller::updateSubscription($subscription->stripe_id, $quantity);
            $subcription->quantity = $stripe_sub_item->quantity;
            $subcription->save();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::error('failed to increment subscription item: ' . $item. ' exception :' . $e);
            throw $e;
        }

        $invoice = \Stripe\Invoice::create([
             'customer' => $team->billing_account->customer->stripe_customer_id,
              'subscription' => $subscription->stripe_id,
        ]);

        $invoice->finalizeInvoice();
        $invoice->pay();

        }
    }
```

Decrement quantity code

```
    public function decrementSubscription(CompanySubscription $subscription) {
        try {
            $quantity = $item->quantity - 1;
            $stripe_sub = StripeBiller::updateSubscription($subscription->stripe_id, $quantity);
            $subscription->quantity = $stripe_sub_item->quantity;
            $subscription->save();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::error('failed to decrement subscription item: ' . $item. ' exception :' . $e);
            throw $e;
        }
    }
```

Create Entity Code

```
$entity = new Entity();
        $entity->name = $request->get('name');
        $entity->save();

           $subscription = CompanySubscription::where('team_id', '=', $team->id)->get()->first();

            if($subscription) {
                 StripeBiller::updateSubscription($subscription, $subscription->quantity + 1);
            } else {           

      StripeBiller::createCompanySubscription($team->billing_account->customer->stripe_customer_id, $request->get('plan'), $team, $entity);
            }
```

Comment: You likely want to use [metadata](https://stripe.com/docs/api/metadata) to track your own value here for "how many entities this customer has paid for this month". Only payments (rather than services you need to provide) should be based on the actual Subscription object's core fields.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, it's a bit rough but this works for anyone who is having a similar problem. [image]